# best way to handle coordinates of multiple people / objects and store that data swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dynamic-arrays

I'll start off by saying I'm very new to this and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to solve this problem.  I'm trying to implement a feature like find my friends through firebase where the location of multiple people is uploaded to my firebase which then pushes the data to all the users in the group.  The problem I'm having is figuring out the best way to store those locations and update them as they come in.

Here's a picture of my firebase structure but I can easily change it if I need to.  The children of "locations" are the `UID` and when new locations become available firebase updates the child instead of making a new one

[image: FireBase Structure]

and here's my code where I was trying to save the info to a `plist` but I'm not married to that idea.  nothing would crash when I called the saveLocations func but I wouldn't get anything in my `plist` either don't need the data to persist so I was thinking about using an array.  I would even parse a json but then it wouldn't be location updates as they are uploaded to the sever (at least at my level of understanding)

```
func saveLocations(value: [LocationFormat]) {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let documentDirectory = paths.object(at: 0) as! String
    let path = documentDirectory.appending("FriendsLocations")
    let dict : NSMutableDictionary = [:]
    dict.write(toFile: path, atomically: false)
    print("Saved to plist")
} 

func retrieveLocations() {
    let retrieveMessageDB = Database.database().reference().child("\(Session.ID)").child("locations")

    retrieveMessageDB.observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

        let lat = snapshotValue["Lat"]!
        let lon = snapshotValue["Lon"]!
        let name = snapshotValue["Name"]
        let locationData = LocationFormat()
        locationData.lat = lat
        locationData.lon = lon
        if name != nil {
            locationData.name = name!
        }

        self.locationArray.append(locationData)
        self.saveLocations(value: self.locationArray)    
    })
}
```

Comment: Look into CoreData

Comment: Thanks. So I went with your advice and used CoreData.  My question now is how do I get CoreData to overwrite the location data for a person instead of making a new entry

Comment: That’s a topic for a different post.